# Symfony autoload.php Error

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to access `Symfony/web/app_dev.php`, but it producing the following errors:

> Fatal error: Class 'Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry' not found in 
>   /var/www/wowddds.com/public_html/Symfony/app/autoload.php on line 35

Guide me, please.

Yes it is fresh , Installation !

Comment: If you go to app/check.php, is it working properly?

Comment: did you follow some kind of tutorial? did you install assets?

Comment: @Ninsuo Same error .... with app/check.php

Comment: Did you installed Symfony2 with vendors?

Comment: No its not with vendors ... i have download zip file from the official site.. then i have followed link http://www.joelverhagen.com/blog/2011/05/how-to-configure-symfony-2-0-on-ubuntu-server-2011-4/

Comment: That's your problem. Get the latest and complete version of symfony2 [there](http://symfony.com/download).

Comment: I have downloaded from here only

Comment: I understood, but take the first symfony2 you see, not the one "without vendors".

Comment: okay i have downloaded again . installing again...

Comment: for your information, the "without vendors" version of symfony let you have the latest version of Symfony, with a manual install of all required vendors to get the latest vendors too. That's harder and discouraged if you're a beginner.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18403/discussion-between-sandeep-kamble-and-ninsuo)

Comment: If problem is solved, please write solution as answer, for other users, and mark it as good answer to close topic.

Answer (score 0):

This bug is possibly due by some version of php such as php 5.4.4 but from 5.4.9 this bug disappear.

I recommend you to update php to the latest version.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

On symfony3 this caused by missing vendors. Try `composer install` or `composer update` ;)